# How to find the day of month in momentjs

Tags: momentjs

how can i find the day of the month that current moment date points to.
like over here  iam trying to invoke dayOfMonth()

```
 var compareDay = function(ts1,ts2){
           return (moment(ts1).dayOfMonth() === moment(ts2).dayOfMonth())?true:false;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/),

> Moment#date is for the date of the month, and Moment#day is for the day of the week.

So I believe you want,

```
return moment(ts1).date() === moment(ts2).date();
```